# ReactJS + Nodejs deploy on Heroku fails to build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment

I've tried deploying my app on heroku using 'git push heroku master' command.
However, the build fails to create and the deploy is rejected. This is what I get:

```
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  14.5.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   6.14.5
       
       Resolving node version 14.5.0...
       Downloading and installing node 14.5.0...
       npm 6.14.5 already installed with node
       
-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules is checked into source control and cannot be cached
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
       Rebuilding any native modules
       
       > nodemailer@6.4.10 postinstall /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/nodemailer
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       
                                  === Nodemailer 6.4.10 ===
       
       Thank you for using Nodemailer for your email sending needs! While Nodemailer
       itself is mostly meant to be a SMTP client there are other related projects in
       the Nodemailer project as well.
       
       > IMAP API (  https://imapapi.com  ) is a server application to easily access
         IMAP accounts via REST API
       > ImapFlow (  https://imapflow.com/  ) is an async IMAP client library for
         Node.js
       > NodemailerApp (  https://nodemailer.com/app/  ) is a cross platform GUI app to
         debug emails
       > Project Pending (  https://projectpending.com/  ) allows you to host DNS of
         your project domains
       > Pending DNS (  https://pendingdns.com/  ) is the DNS server used that powers
         Project Pending
       > Ethereal Email (  https://ethereal.email/  ) is an email testing service that
         accepts all your test emails
       
       ........
       
       > nodemon@2.0.4 postinstall /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/nodemon
       > node bin/postinstall || exit 0
       
       Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
        > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate
       
       body-parser@1.19.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/body-parser
       bytes@3.1.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/bytes
       content-type@1.0.4 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/content-type
       debug@2.6.9 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/debug
       ms@2.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/ms
       depd@1.1.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/depd
       http-errors@1.7.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/http-errors
       inherits@2.0.3 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/inherits
       setprototypeof@1.1.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/setprototypeof
       statuses@1.5.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/statuses
       toidentifier@1.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/toidentifier
       iconv-lite@0.4.24 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/iconv-lite
       safer-buffer@2.1.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/safer-buffer
       on-finished@2.3.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/on-finished
       ee-first@1.1.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/ee-first
       qs@6.7.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/qs
       raw-body@2.4.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/raw-body
       unpipe@1.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/unpipe
       type-is@1.6.18 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/type-is
       media-typer@0.3.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/media-typer
       mime-types@2.1.27 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/mime-types
       mime-db@1.44.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/mime-db
       concurrently@5.2.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/concurrently
       chalk@2.4.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/chalk
       ansi-styles@3.2.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/ansi-styles
       color-convert@1.9.3 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/color-convert
       color-name@1.1.3 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/color-name
       escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/escape-string-regexp
       supports-color@5.5.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/chalk/node_modules/supports-color
       has-flag@3.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/has-flag
       date-fns@2.14.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/date-fns
       lodash@4.17.19 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/lodash
       read-pkg@4.0.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/read-pkg
       normalize-package-data@2.5.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/normalize-package-data
       hosted-git-info@2.8.8 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/hosted-git-info
       resolve@1.17.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/resolve
       path-parse@1.0.6 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/path-parse
       semver@5.7.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/semver
       validate-npm-package-license@3.0.4 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license
       spdx-correct@3.1.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/spdx-correct
       spdx-expression-parse@3.0.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/spdx-expression-parse
       spdx-exceptions@2.3.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/spdx-exceptions
       spdx-license-ids@3.0.5 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/spdx-license-ids
       parse-json@4.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/parse-json
       error-ex@1.3.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/error-ex
       is-arrayish@0.2.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/is-arrayish
       json-parse-better-errors@1.0.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/json-parse-better-errors
       pify@3.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/pify
       rxjs@6.6.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/rxjs
       tslib@1.13.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/tslib
       spawn-command@0.0.2-1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/spawn-command
       supports-color@6.1.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/supports-color
       tree-kill@1.2.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/tree-kill
       yargs@13.3.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/yargs
       cliui@5.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/cliui
       string-width@3.1.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/string-width
       emoji-regex@7.0.3 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/emoji-regex
       is-fullwidth-code-point@2.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/is-fullwidth-code-point
       strip-ansi@5.2.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/strip-ansi
       ansi-regex@4.1.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/ansi-regex
       wrap-ansi@5.1.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/wrap-ansi
       find-up@3.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/find-up
       locate-path@3.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/locate-path
       p-locate@3.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/p-locate
       p-limit@2.3.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/p-limit
       p-try@2.2.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/p-try
       path-exists@3.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/path-exists
       get-caller-file@2.0.5 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/get-caller-file
       require-directory@2.1.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/require-directory
       require-main-filename@2.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/require-main-filename
       set-blocking@2.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/set-blocking
       which-module@2.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/which-module
       y18n@4.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/y18n
       yargs-parser@13.1.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/yargs-parser
       camelcase@5.3.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/camelcase
       decamelize@1.2.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/decamelize
       express@4.17.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/express
       accepts@1.3.7 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/accepts
       negotiator@0.6.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/negotiator
       array-flatten@1.1.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/array-flatten
       content-disposition@0.5.3 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/content-disposition
       safe-buffer@5.1.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/safe-buffer
       cookie@0.4.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/cookie
       cookie-signature@1.0.6 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/cookie-signature
       encodeurl@1.0.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/encodeurl
       escape-html@1.0.3 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/escape-html
       etag@1.8.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/etag
       finalhandler@1.1.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/finalhandler
       parseurl@1.3.3 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/parseurl
       fresh@0.5.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/fresh
       merge-descriptors@1.0.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/merge-descriptors
       methods@1.1.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/methods
       path-to-regexp@0.1.7 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/path-to-regexp
       proxy-addr@2.0.6 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/proxy-addr
       forwarded@0.1.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/forwarded
       ipaddr.js@1.9.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/ipaddr.js
       range-parser@1.2.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/range-parser
       send@0.17.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/send
       destroy@1.0.4 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/destroy
       mime@1.6.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/mime
       ms@2.1.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/send/node_modules/ms
       serve-static@1.14.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/serve-static
       utils-merge@1.0.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/utils-merge
       vary@1.1.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/vary
       nodemailer@6.4.10 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/nodemailer
       nodemon@2.0.4 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/nodemon
       chokidar@3.4.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/chokidar
       anymatch@3.1.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/anymatch
       normalize-path@3.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/normalize-path
       picomatch@2.2.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/picomatch
       braces@3.0.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/braces
       fill-range@7.0.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/fill-range
       to-regex-range@5.0.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/to-regex-range
       is-number@7.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/is-number
       glob-parent@5.1.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/glob-parent
       is-glob@4.0.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/is-glob
       is-extglob@2.1.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/is-extglob
       is-binary-path@2.1.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/is-binary-path
       binary-extensions@2.1.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/binary-extensions
       readdirp@3.4.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/readdirp
       debug@3.2.6 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/debug
       ms@2.1.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/ms
       ignore-by-default@1.0.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/ignore-by-default
       minimatch@3.0.4 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/minimatch
       brace-expansion@1.1.11 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/brace-expansion
       balanced-match@1.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/balanced-match
       concat-map@0.0.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/concat-map
       pstree.remy@1.1.8 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/pstree.remy
       supports-color@5.5.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/supports-color
       touch@3.1.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/touch
       nopt@1.0.10 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/nopt
       abbrev@1.1.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/abbrev
       undefsafe@2.0.3 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/undefsafe
       update-notifier@4.1.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/update-notifier
       boxen@4.2.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/boxen
       ansi-align@3.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/ansi-align
       chalk@3.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/boxen/node_modules/chalk
       ansi-styles@4.2.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/boxen/node_modules/ansi-styles
       @types/color-name@1.1.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/@types/color-name
       color-convert@2.0.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/boxen/node_modules/color-convert
       color-name@1.1.4 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/boxen/node_modules/color-name
       supports-color@7.1.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/boxen/node_modules/supports-color
       has-flag@4.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/boxen/node_modules/has-flag
       cli-boxes@2.2.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/cli-boxes
       string-width@4.2.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/boxen/node_modules/string-width
       emoji-regex@8.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/boxen/node_modules/emoji-regex
       is-fullwidth-code-point@3.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/boxen/node_modules/is-fullwidth-code-point
       strip-ansi@6.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/boxen/node_modules/strip-ansi
       ansi-regex@5.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/boxen/node_modules/ansi-regex
       term-size@2.2.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/term-size
       type-fest@0.8.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/type-fest
       widest-line@3.1.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/widest-line
       string-width@4.2.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/widest-line/node_modules/string-width
       emoji-regex@8.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/widest-line/node_modules/emoji-regex
       is-fullwidth-code-point@3.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/widest-line/node_modules/is-fullwidth-code-point
       strip-ansi@6.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/widest-line/node_modules/strip-ansi
       ansi-regex@5.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/widest-line/node_modules/ansi-regex
       chalk@3.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/chalk
       ansi-styles@4.2.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/ansi-styles
       color-convert@2.0.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/color-convert
       color-name@1.1.4 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/color-name
       supports-color@7.1.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/supports-color
       has-flag@4.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/has-flag
       configstore@5.0.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/configstore
       dot-prop@5.2.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/dot-prop
       is-obj@2.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/is-obj
       graceful-fs@4.2.4 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/graceful-fs
       make-dir@3.1.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/make-dir
       semver@6.3.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/make-dir/node_modules/semver
       unique-string@2.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/unique-string
       crypto-random-string@2.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/crypto-random-string
       write-file-atomic@3.0.3 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/write-file-atomic
       imurmurhash@0.1.4 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/imurmurhash
       is-typedarray@1.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/is-typedarray
       signal-exit@3.0.3 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/signal-exit
       typedarray-to-buffer@3.1.5 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/typedarray-to-buffer
       xdg-basedir@4.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/xdg-basedir
       has-yarn@2.1.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/has-yarn
       import-lazy@2.1.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/import-lazy
       is-ci@2.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/is-ci
       ci-info@2.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/ci-info
       is-installed-globally@0.3.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/is-installed-globally
       global-dirs@2.0.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/global-dirs
       ini@1.3.5 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/ini
       is-path-inside@3.0.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/is-path-inside
       is-npm@4.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/is-npm
       is-yarn-global@0.3.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/is-yarn-global
       latest-version@5.1.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/latest-version
       package-json@6.5.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/package-json
       got@9.6.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/got
       @sindresorhus/is@0.14.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/@sindresorhus/is
       @szmarczak/http-timer@1.1.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/@szmarczak/http-timer
       defer-to-connect@1.1.3 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/defer-to-connect
       cacheable-request@6.1.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/cacheable-request
       clone-response@1.0.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/clone-response
       mimic-response@1.0.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/mimic-response
       get-stream@5.1.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/cacheable-request/node_modules/get-stream
       pump@3.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/pump
       end-of-stream@1.4.4 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/end-of-stream
       once@1.4.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/once
       wrappy@1.0.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/wrappy
       http-cache-semantics@4.1.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/http-cache-semantics
       keyv@3.1.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/keyv
       json-buffer@3.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/json-buffer
       lowercase-keys@2.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/cacheable-request/node_modules/lowercase-keys
       normalize-url@4.5.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/normalize-url
       responselike@1.0.2 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/responselike
       lowercase-keys@1.0.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/lowercase-keys
       decompress-response@3.3.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/decompress-response
       duplexer3@0.1.4 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/duplexer3
       get-stream@4.1.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/get-stream
       p-cancelable@1.1.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/p-cancelable
       to-readable-stream@1.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/to-readable-stream
       url-parse-lax@3.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/url-parse-lax
       prepend-http@2.0.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/prepend-http
       registry-auth-token@4.1.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/registry-auth-token
       rc@1.2.8 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/rc
       deep-extend@0.6.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/deep-extend
       minimist@1.2.5 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/minimist
       strip-json-comments@2.0.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/strip-json-comments
       registry-url@5.1.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/registry-url
       semver@6.3.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/package-json/node_modules/semver
       pupa@2.0.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/pupa
       escape-goat@2.1.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/escape-goat
       semver-diff@3.1.1 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/semver-diff
       semver@6.3.0 /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da/node_modules/semver-diff/node_modules/semver
       Installing any new modules (package.json)
       audited 227 packages in 1.923s
       
       11 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
       
-----> Build
       Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts
       Running heroku-postbuild
       
       > 360-website@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da
       > npm run build
       
       
       > 360-website@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_db35b4d19b0851b5efd93d47b201c8da
       > react-scripts build
       
sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! 360-website@1.0.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the 360-website@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.tiVOf/_logs/2020-07-10T13_38_33_627Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! 360-website@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the 360-website@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.tiVOf/_logs/2020-07-10T13_38_33_640Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - node_modules checked into source control
         https://blog.heroku.com/node-habits-2016#9-only-git-the-important-bits
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Here is the link to my repository: https://github.com/mw365787/360-website

This problem started happening when I installed node package in my app. Before that, there was no issues.
I've tried to ignore node-modules file in repository and all the tips and tricks they stated on support.

Comment: Please check again your code, make sure it build successfully in local first. I saw some syntax error in the above console.

Comment: Its probably your syntax error, make sure to test it locally

Comment: I've tried to run it locally, and yes, there was a syntax error in form of wrong proxy path for my localhost.
However, the problem with git push remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting H10 errors, can't access the link you have given, then try this

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
  
  
  For removing H10 errors replace above with ---
  
"scripts": {
"dev": "react-scripts start",
"start": "serve -s build",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
"eject": "react-scripts eject",
"heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
}
```

Comment: I created a new app and repository on Heroku and it deployed without any errors, however if I try to overwrite already existing app, the errors I posted above occur again...